# Run Google Analytics Request in a Chrome Extension Background Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background-process

Here I have this code, which runs a request to google analytics (I checked, that part works in a popup script) and I would like it to send a daily "order" so to speak to let me know how many daily uses I have installed.

I have set the interval to 5 seconds for testing purposes, but this does not seem to work anyway.

```
function doSomething() {

 chrome.storage.sync.get('session', function(result){
var val = result.session;
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "http://bat.global.cf:8000/checkok.html?rando="+val);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-232507651-1&cid="+val+"&t=pageview&dp=%2Fdaily24hCheck");
xhttp.send();
 });

}

setInterval(doSomething, 5000); // Time in milliseconds


/*Anonymous anylitics code for a background script  end*/
```

Is there something I am missing about background scripts? The request does not seem to be sent, how can I fix this?

Comment: Open [devtools for the background script](/a/10258029) and inspect what happens, don't guess.

Comment: What manifest version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact that they are not persistently executing. See the [Migrating to Service Workers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#alarms) documentation:

> It's common for web developers to perform delayed or periodic operations using the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` methods. These APIs can fail in service workers, though, **because the scheduler will cancel the timers when the service worker is terminated.**

The idiomatic way to achieve what you want here is to use the [`chrome.alarms` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/), which is also discussed at that link.

Note that "armed" alarms won't survive a full extension restart (e.g. if the browser is restarted), so you probably should save the last time your alarm code has successfully executed and check if you need to send a beacon / when should you schedule a new alarm on extension start (e.g. through `chrome.runtime.onStartup`).